# Validate an empty Set with Bean Validation

Tags: jakarta-ee, set, bean-validation, is-empty

I try to do a bean validation for a `Set` property in an entity:

```
@NotEmpty
@Valid
private Set<E_CMS_CONDITION_ITEM> items;
```

I would like to give me an error when the `Set` is empty, now did not give me an error. Is this possible with bean validation? If it is how?

**UPDATE**
For Hardy:
I am using primefaces 5.2 version and this is my xhtml code:

```
<p:dataList id="conditionItemList" value="#{eventsController.model.currentCondition.items}" var="event" type="ordered" rowIndexVar="rowInd" label="#{msg['table.conditions.caption']}">
    .
    .
    .
</p:dataList>
<h:message for="conditionItemList" style="color:red" />
```

bean validations on same xhtml are working, just this not. Did not write any error, I also try with `@NotNull` but the same.

Comment: Could you please refine your question?  You should get a constraint violations when validating null or the empty set. Are you saying this is not happening for you. In this case you will need to share more context.

Comment: I did not get any error for this, I updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Hibernate Validator](http://hibernate.org/validator/documentation/getting-started/). Its the reference implemmentation of [Bean Validation 1.1 JSR-349](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=349)

You could validate the entity that contains `items`.

```
  ValidatorFactory factory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
  Validator validator = factory.getValidator();
  Set<ConstraintViolation<Foo>> constraintViolations =
      validator.validate( entity );
```

It will return the validation for the entity, including the violations generated by `items`

Comment: I don`t want to write a validator for this, if it is possible I would like to do it with bean validation.

Comment: You are not writing any validator, you are using the validator provided by Hibernate, which is the reference implementation of latest Bean Validation Specification. Maybe I have misunderstood your question. Could you be more specific please?. Maybe the context where you want to do the validation.

Comment: Yes but I need to write a Validator.class where I put that validator provided by Hibernate. I dont want to write any Validator.class. If it is possible I would do validations just from annotations. Possible because of my English is the misunderstood, sorry for it.